# Zephyr: panic alarm after exiting a thread

Tags: multithreading, zephyr-rtos

I have a simple thread, created by

```
    k_thread_create(&bme2380_thread,bme280_stack,K_THREAD_STACK_SIZEOF(bme280_stack),bme280_handler,
        NULL, NULL, NULL,   // some of these NULL's will be changed to something meaningful
        1,  // priority
        K_ESSENTIAL | K_USER,
        K_NO_WAIT
    );
```

Inside it, I have a `while (true) { }` loop, receiving and handling messages. There is a special message that instruct the thread to `break` the loop and exit the thread function. Seems simple, however after exiting something happens with the stack and Kernel panic is activated:

```
00:00:30.767,578] <inf> hello: I will stop BME280 thread
[00:00:30.767,608] <inf> hello: my_thread_handler triggered
[00:00:30.767,639] <inf> hello: Someone has stopped us.
[00:00:30.767,639] <inf> hello: my_thread_handler exited
[00:00:30.767,669] <err> os: r0/a1:  0x00000004  r1/a2:  0x00000008  r2/a3:  0x00000007
[00:00:30.767,669] <err> os: r3/a4:  0x00000005 r12/ip:  0x200070f4 r14/lr:  0x00004adb
[00:00:30.767,700] <err> os:  xpsr:  0x61000000
[00:00:30.767,730] <err> os: Faulting instruction address (r15/pc): 0x000091e4
[00:00:30.767,761] <err> os: >>> ZEPHYR FATAL ERROR 4: Kernel panic on CPU 0
[00:00:30.767,791] <err> os: Current thread: 0x200048a0 (unknown)
```

What happens when a thread passes its '}' ?

Here is the whole thread:

```
void bme280_handler(void* p1, void* p2, void* p3)
{
    LOG_INF("my_thread_handler entered");
    while (true) {
        int data;
        k_msgq_get(&my_msgq, &data, K_FOREVER);
        LOG_INF("my_thread_handler triggered");
        // here is real work done including sending data to host (chest)
        if (data == -1) {
            LOG_INF("Someone has stopped us.");
            break;
        }
    }
    LOG_INF("my_thread_handler exited");
}
```